# Nikon D5100: should I avoid the firmware update if I want to use 3rd party batteries?

Tags: nikon, battery, nikon-d5100, firmware, third-party

I want buy batteries for my Nikon D5100. Third party options are much cheaper than Nikon's one. I saw offers from Wasabi and Vivitar, I guess are others in the market. I note that both has significantly more power than the genuine from Nikon (1500mA and 2300mA vs 1030mA).

On the other hand I'm reading "[The last D3100, D3200, D5100, D5200 and P7700 firmware update killed third party battery compatibility](http://nikonrumors.com/2013/12/08/the-last-d3100-d3200-d5100-d5200-and-p7700-firmware-update-killed-third-party-battery-compatibility.aspx/#ixzz3N2IN7gip)" and my camera has the following firmware version:

- A 1.00
- B 1.00
- L 1.003

I also read that this [firmware update](http://www.dpreview.com/articles/2823420050/nikon-updates-firmware-for-d3100-d3200-d5100-d5200-p7700) is not so important, or in other words, didn't bring important features.

My questions:

1. Should I update the firmware? (maybe exist some other power reason)
2. What batteries do you recommend for Nikon D5100?

Thanks

Comment: Note that some (not all) generic batteries lie about their capacity — the number is bigger, but in actual use, not so much.

Answer (score 1):

Firmware updates are good. It is right that they killed third party battery compatibility. But you can overcome this problem with a patch by [Simeon](https://nikonhacker.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know [link](https://nikonhacker.com)